# initiate click on div status

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the following if the `div='tab-content'` is open then only i want to initiate a click command else not.How to do this with jquery and bootstrap

```
<label class="radio-inline">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#rules_home" id="rules_container">Rules</a>
     <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="collapse" id="rules_home"><textarea rows="5" cols="70" readonly id="rules_data"></textarea></div>
     </div>
</label>
<label><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> </label>

<script>
$(':button').click(function(){

    $("#rules_container").click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is the accordion

Answer (score 0):

try to use $("#rules_container").trigger('click');

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="radio-inline">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#rules_home" id="rules_container">Rules</a>
     <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="collapse" id="rules_home"><textarea rows="5" cols="70" readonly id="rules_data"></textarea></div>
     </div>
</label>
<label><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> </label>

<script>
$(':button').click(function(){
    $("#rules_container").trigger('click');
});
/* alert 'click' if #rules_container was clicked */
$('#rules_container').click(function(){
 alert('click')
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emulate a click on an element use the trigger method.

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    $("#rules_container").trigger('click');
});
$('#rules_container').on("click", function(){
    alert('click')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering 'open' means display:block (if div is shown)

```
<script>
if($(".tab-content").css("display") == "block" ){
    $(':button').click(function(){
    // do what you want 
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this for example:

```
function someHandler() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('class-a')) {
        //do something specific to a
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('class-b')) {
        //do something specific to b
    }
    if ($this.hasClass('class-c')) {
        //do something specific to c
    }
}

$(".class-a, .class-b, .class-c").click(someHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to trigger click when tab-content is hidden, you can try this:

```
    $(':button').click(function(){
       if(!$('.tab-content:visible').length)
         $("#rules_container").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: want to trigger click if it is not hidden.How to do that?

Comment: just remove "!"
   $(':button').click(function(){
       if($('.tab-content:visible').length)
         $("#rules_container").trigger('click');
});